# Passing database value to variable

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm rarely ask on here, so first of all I'm sorry if my question is readable or not allowed here. So what I'm trying to do here is passing the username from LoginActivity into the player1 variable at HomeActivity . here's the code for the HomeActivity.java class

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    TextView NameTxt;
    TextView CoinTxt;
    TextView GemTxt;

    String p1name = player1.getName();
    int p1coin = player1.getCoins();
    int p1gem = player1.getGems();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

//////TV declare///////

       NameTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerName);
       CoinTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cointxt);
       GemTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gemtxt);

       NameTxt.setText(p1name);
       CoinTxt.setText("Coin: " +p1coin);
       GemTxt.setText("Gem: " +p1gem);
   }
}
```

And this is LoginActivity.class

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edit1;
    EditText edit2;
    EditText edit3;

    Button registerBtn;
    Button loginBtn;

    DatabaseHelper myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Set fullscreen and no title//////////
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

///////////////////////////////////////
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

        edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpname);
        edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpemail);
        edit3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editppw);

        registerBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
        loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

         loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (validate()) {
                    String Email = edit2.getText().toString();
                    String Password = edit3.getText().toString();

                    User currentUser = myDb.Authenticate(new User(null, null, Email, Password));

                        if (currentUser != null) {
                            System.out.println("Successfull");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {

                           System.out.println("Unsuccessfull");

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (validate()) {
                        String UserName = edit1.getText().toString();
                        String Email = edit2.getText().toString();
                        String Password = edit3.getText().toString();

                        if (!myDb.isEmailExists(Email)) {
                                myDb.addUser(player1);
                            public User player1 = new User(null, UserName, Email, Password);
                        }
                    } 
                }
            });
        }

        public boolean validate() {
            boolean valid = false;
            String Email = edit2.getText().toString();
            String Password = edit3.getText().toString();

            if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
                valid = false;
                 edit2.setError("Please enter valid email!");
            } else {
                valid = true;
                 edit2.setError(null);
            }

            if (Password.isEmpty()) {
                valid = false;
                  edit3.setError("Please enter valid password!");
           } else {
               if (Password.length() > 5) {
               valid = true;
               edit3.setError(null);
           } else {
               valid = false;
                 edit3.setError("Password is to short!");
           }
       } 
       return valid;
   }
```

}

And I also have simple User.java class

```
String id;
String userName;
String email;
String password;
int coins;
int gems;

public User(String id, String userName, String email, String password) {

    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
   //And so on. Don't mind this

}

public String getName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public int getCoins() {
    return this.coins;
}

public int getGems() {
    return this.gems;
}
```

And I write the short code , for the sake of readability.
I get an error on
myDb.addUser(player1);
And the one below it.

I'm just trying to make so that the player name equals to the value of Username on the database . and also the coins and gems too. Can you guys help me to get the idea how to pass the value? It tooks me whole 3days to figure a way to fix this. And it just blew my brain. So maybe you guys can help me

Comment: To pass data from 1 activity to another you pass it using an Intent Extra, loads of example around.

Comment: I'll search for it. BTW thanks, I'll post my update soon

Comment: you calling reference player1 of class 'Player' before defining it

Comment: It still return an error Illegal modifier for player1; only final is permitted. On LoginActivity.java

Comment: Thanks Ali Ahsan. Your comment make me think 10x over and over again. I've fixed it. So I put   User player1;  on top . and replace the error line with player1 = new User(null, userName, Email, Password);

Comment: np glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the database stuff and assuming that LoginActivity is started from another activity (MainActivity) then you could adapt the following which passes the Username and UserId (ample to then get any additional data in the HomeActivity from the database).

So this when it starts immediately invokes the **LoginActivity**.

Clicking **Login** (mimics getting user and id from db) starts the **HomeActivity** passing the Username and userid via Intent Extras.

The **HomeActivity** displays the username and userid, and additionally a **DONE** button.

Clicking the **DONE** button **returns** back through the stack (skippng LoginActivity as that was finished) to the **MainActivity** which changes the TextView from **Hello World** to **Welcome Back** (not that you'd ever see Hello World).

### MainActivity.java :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMessage = this.findViewById(R.id.message);

        // Immediately start Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMessage.setText("Welcome back");
    }
}
```

### LoginActivity.java :-

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String INTENTKEY_USERNAME = "IK_USERNAME";
    public static final String INTENTKEY_USERID = "IK_USERID";

    Button mloginbtn;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mContext = this;
        mloginbtn = this.findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        mloginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext,HomeActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(INTENTKEY_USERNAME,"Fred");
                i.putExtra(INTENTKEY_USERID,99L);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mUsername, muserid;
    Button mDone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mUsername = this.findViewById(R.id.username);
        muserid = this.findViewById(R.id.userid);
        mDone = this.findViewById(R.id.done);
        mDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        mUsername.setText(i.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.INTENTKEY_USERNAME));
        muserid.setText(String.valueOf(i.getLongExtra(LoginActivity.INTENTKEY_USERID,0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, my main activity is the loading screen, is this still applicable

Comment: yep MainActivity is the first display, just you don't get to see it as it, just straight away starts the Login display (it could a have menu/button to select login/register user and so on just not needed for the demo.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

```
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", Bob)
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    ...
```

and then in home have:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String easyPuzzle = intent.getExtras().getString("username");
```

Comment: This question supposedly answered. But I have another problem. Because of I'm passing many data, I'm using bundle. The problem is, when I click the login button, the screen not changing like before it change to HomeActivity . but now it stays at LoginActivity. I  can'tseem to get the problem

Comment: can you update your files on here? I want to make sure nothing changed before responding

Comment: Let's assume this one as solved. I'll post it as the new question. I hope you there to help me. I'll post it in 4 hours from now.